# Cloudera VM, compression codecs

Tags: hadoop, compression, cloudera

I am preparing for CLOUDERA certification and some times it's very difficult to remember the compression codecs used in Sqoop import process.
For example: org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.SnappyCodec.
I will not be allowed to use google during the exam.

During the exam, is there anyway to retrieve this information?

Currently, I use Cloudera Quickstart VM and I did not find this information in Mapred-site.xml.
Where can I find the same?

Comment: Depends on the tools being used... You have access to all the documentation for each tool, so know how to navigate the documentation, not memorize the obscure classnames.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm fairly certain you have access to Cloudera documentation

https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-14-x/topics/introduction_compression.html

As well as Hadoop JavaDoc

Just find the `org.apache.hadoop.io.compress` package